# @SecondaryTable annotation not working with same table name in different Schema

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have two tables with the same name in different schemas and I am trying to create an entity using both these tables and @SecondaryTable. It gives me the following error

```
InFlightMetadataCollector$DuplicateSecondaryTableException: Table with that name [EMPLOYEE] already associated with entity
```

Here is my code

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE", schema = "S1", catalog = "")
@SecondaryTable(name = "EMPLOYEE",  schema = "S2", catalog = "", pkJoinColumns = {@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "EID", referencedColumnName = "ENO")})
public class Employee {
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is a bug in Hibernate, Hibernate ORM team says on the ticket [HHH-12423](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-12423) that this is fixed and will be available from hibernate version 5.3.0

Answer (score 0):

name needs to be unique in order to be referenced inside the column annotation ... I have two ideas which I didn't try .... you can make an alias to one database table if you have privelege to do and then refer to this alias (i don't know if it works or no) .... or you can define the table name as "s1.employee" and "s2.employee" , some providers allow it but i am not sure if hibernate does or no ... if any of these worked with u please let us know